# Python plot multiple graphs one after another with matplotlib in PyCharm with interactive mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I want to plot multiple graphs and have a rest between them.

So like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def create_plot():
    plt.plot()
    plt.show()

for _ in range(3):
    create_plot()
    input("Next?")
```

The matplotlib windows open one after another while looping but the actual data only first gets drawn when the loop is finished.
It only occurs when using PyCharm, in the console there is a line saying: **"Backend MacOSX is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on."**
How can I avoid that?